# Disapperiang IPhone Numeric Keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, keypad

How I can disappear **numeric keyboard** in iPhone because there is no return key in it, which implies it is not going to respond to

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

Comment: Duplicate of: - <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442491>
- <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649777>
- <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273439>
- <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/804563>
- <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963571>
- <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328230>
- <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866419>
- <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176877> And that was just on the first page of search results...

Comment: I am afraid you are wrong because they all are talking about when Keyboard is not of Numeric Type, I know how to disable the keyboard when its not numeric, its different case, when you have to disappear "NUMERIC Keyboard". And i search before putting that question.

Comment: You can easily put a button on your screen to dismiss the keyboard once the user has entered the number.  Isn't that how the phone app works?  Or you could put a toolbar above the keyboard with a "don" button on it, or any number of things (automatically dismiss the keyboard after x seconds of inactivity, once the text in the field validates, etc etc)

Comment: [theTextField resignFirstResponder]; works no matter what keyboard you have.

Comment: Dave you are a nice guy, but you are hooked on trying to find duplicate answers.  You are really smart though.  Can you look at this question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360140/adding-done-button-to-only-number-pad-keyboard-on-iphone

Comment: @Bryan and you seem to be a guy hooked on finding my answers that just list links to duplicate questions.  I promise there are others (more than a thousand others, in fact).

Answer (score 3):

Use [resignFirstResponder](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSResponder/resignFirstResponder) in touchesBegan, like so:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
    if(touch.phase == UITouchPhaseBegan) {
        [self.myTextField resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

You may need to call this on multiple text fields if you're not sure where the focus is currently located; I haven't tested that case.

Additionally, in Interface Builder, you'll need to enable the "User Interaction Enabled" checkbox for the view, or programatically use:

```
myView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the answer..

```
-(void) touchesBegan :(NSSet *) touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event

{

    //[URL resignFirstResponder];

    //[Password resignFirstResponder];

    [speedField resignFirstResponder];

    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event ];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[theTextField resignFirstResponder];
```

Comment: Well you do this within the function which i have wrote above, like this. 

Anyhow where i should put this code to work?

Comment: i have many textfield in my view and also its not working for number keypad

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use "Numbers and Punctuation" keyboard instead of "Numeric"? It will save your time

Answer (score -2):

Here you go.  Extend your UIViewController Class with this.  But how do we know it is the done button?  [Adding Done Button to Only Number Pad Keyboard on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360140/adding-done-button-to-only-number-pad-keyboard-on-iphone)

```
//
//  UIViewController+NumPadReturn.m
//  iGenerateRandomNumbers
//
//  Created by  on 12/4/10.
//  Copyright 2010 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "UIViewController+NumPadReturn.h"


@implementation UIViewController (NumPadReturn)

-(void) viewDidLoad{
    // add observer for the respective notifications (depending on the os version)
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.2) {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                                 selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) 
                                                     name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification 
                                                   object:nil];     
    } else {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                                 selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:) 
                                                     name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification 
                                                   object:nil];
    }

}


- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note {
    // if clause is just an additional precaution, you could also dismiss it
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] < 3.2) {
        [self addButtonToKeyboard];
    }
}

- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)note {
    // if clause is just an additional precaution, you could also dismiss it
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.2) {
        [self addButtonToKeyboard];
    }
}

- (void)addButtonToKeyboard {
    // create custom button
    UIButton *doneButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    doneButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 163, 106, 53);
    doneButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.0) {
        [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneUp3.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneDown3.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    } else {        
        [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneUp.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [doneButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DoneDown.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    }
    [doneButton addTarget:self action:@selector(doneButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    // locate keyboard view
    UIWindow* tempWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] objectAtIndex:1];
    UIView* keyboard;
    for(int i=0; i<[tempWindow.subviews count]; i++) {
        keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];

        // keyboard found, add the button
        if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 3.2) {
            if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHost"] == YES)
                [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];
        } else {
            if([[keyboard description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard"] == YES)
                [keyboard addSubview:doneButton];
        }
    }


}

- (void)doneButton:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"doneButton");
    [self.view endEditing:TRUE];
}
```

Comment: -1 this is a total hack and shouldn't be used.  What if apple decides to change the name of "UIKeyboard" to `UIKBView?` You should never rely on undocumented behavior or implementation details to make your code work properly.  If you need behavior that's not possible without undocumented stuff, file a bug.