# iOS number pad keyboard with ability to switch on text keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, numpad

I have a text field that I want to have a keyboard like this when user start typing:

[image]

please also see this video: https://youtu.be/iU_jocny3N0

As you can see in this video there is a "ABC" key that helps user to switch from number pad to text. and also when press "123" in text the keyboard switchs from text to number pad.  I am wondering how they do this?

The only solution that I found was adding a subview to keyboard like what described here:

[Adding Done Button to Only Number Pad Keyboard on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4360140/adding-done-button-to-only-number-pad-keyboard-on-iphone)

but this way may not work when user uses custom keyboards. and also do not works for switching from text to number pad.

Or as another solution I know `accessoryInputView` but this is not like the video. It adds a toolbar above the keyboard.

Does someone knows the solutions that is used in this video?

Comment: In my old project I have added My Custom button on Keyboard . But it is Objc code

Comment: Are you add this by adding a subview to the uiwindow?

Comment: Nope , in To the Keyboard !!!

Comment: can you share the code?

Comment: May be you can also look at the Custom Keyboard Extension https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/CustomKeyboard.html

Comment: I do not want to develop a custom keyboard extension, I want to give the ability to user for switching between numberpad and text keyboard. Custom keyboards is a separate keyboard that user must select it from setting and it will be used for all apps of the user.

Comment: @HuseinBehboodiRad Added code Please check

Comment: @HuseinBehboodiRad Please first create demo project in Objective C then implement same code.

Comment: Thanks. Please read the comment below the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have added comma button to the keyboard,

Keyboard is also a simple **UIView**  Which contains **Controls**

NOTE: This is old code was working in my old project Not tested in new projects

```
- (void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)note {
    // create custom button

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Some code
        UITextField *txt = (UITextField *)[self.view findFirstResponder];
        if (txt.keyboardType == UIKeyboardTypeDecimalPad) {
            UIButton * btnComma = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [btnComma setTag:15000];

            UIView* keyboard = [self findKeyboard];

//            btnComma.frame = CGRectMake(0, 162, 126, 54);

            btnComma.frame = [self findKeySizeForView:keyboard];







            if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")) {
                [btnComma setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 20, 0)];
            }

            [btnComma setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithHexString:@"CBD0D6"]];
            btnComma.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
            [btnComma setTitle:@"." forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btnComma setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btnComma.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:35.0f]];
            [btnComma addTarget:self action:@selector(commaBtnTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

            [keyboard addSubview:btnComma];
            btnComma = nil;
        }
    });
}
- (UIView *) viewWithPrefix:(NSString *)prefix inView:(UIView *)view {
    for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
        if ([[subview description] hasPrefix:prefix]) {
            return subview;
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

This method for finding keyboard from **UIWindow**

```
- (UIView *) findKeyboard {
    for (UIWindow* window in [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows) {
        UIView *inputSetContainer = [self viewWithPrefix:@"<UIInputSetContainerView" inView:window];
        if (inputSetContainer) {
            UIView *inputSetHost = [self viewWithPrefix:@"<UIInputSetHostView" inView:inputSetContainer];
            if (inputSetHost) {
                UIView *kbinputbackdrop = [self viewWithPrefix:@"<_UIKBCompatInput" inView:inputSetHost];
                if (kbinputbackdrop) {
                    UIView *theKeyboard = [self viewWithPrefix:@"<UIKeyboard" inView:kbinputbackdrop];
                    return theKeyboard;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

and For finding size of bottom right button

```
- (CGRect ) findKeySizeForView:(UIView *)view {
    if (view != nil) {
        UIView *uiKeyboardImpl = [self viewWithPrefix:@"<UIKeyboardImpl" inView:view];
        if (uiKeyboardImpl != nil) {
            UIView *uiKeyboardLayoutStar = [self viewWithPrefix:@"<UIKeyboardLayoutStar" inView:uiKeyboardImpl];
            if (uiKeyboardLayoutStar != nil) {
                UIView *uiKBKeyplaneView = [self viewWithPrefix:@"<UIKBKeyplaneView" inView:uiKeyboardLayoutStar];
                if (uiKBKeyplaneView != nil) {
                    for (view in [uiKBKeyplaneView subviews]) {
                        CGPoint pointOrigin =  view.layer.frame.origin;
                        if (pointOrigin.x <= 0 && pointOrigin.y == uiKBKeyplaneView.frame.size.height - view.frame.size.height && [[view description] hasPrefix:@"<UIKBKeyView"])
                            return  view.layer.frame;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
    return CGRectZero;
}
```

Comment: findKeySizeForView may not work right if user uses a custom button. Am I right? Maybe be the right button in the custom button be a essential key.

Comment: findKeySizeForView Is a method to get exact size of button from keyboard !! so `btnComma.frame`  is assigned from the return size of that function

Comment: let me try it. I guess the code will works but worry about custom keyboards but I will test it with custom keyboards too. let me some time.

Comment: @HuseinBehboodiRad Good Luck !!

Comment: may you please have look at this video : https://youtu.be/iU_jocny3N0 it is not seems that they adding a subview to the keyboard. I am wondering what are they doing?